# Filter dictionary in list by value

Tags: python

```
>>> my_list = [{u'name': u'name1', u'color': u'red'}, {u'name': u'name2', u'color': u'blue'}]
>>> my_list[0]
{u'color': u'red', u'name': u'name1'}
>>> my_list[1]
{u'color': u'blue', u'name': u'name2'}
```

How can I filter from `my_list` dict that contains `'color': u'blue'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the list and find the item which has `blue` as `color` key value.

```
next(i for i in my_list if i['color'] == 'blue')
```